# updating device gcm registration id on OS update

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement update device GCM registration id on android OS update for my app to receive push notification even after OS update. I read somewhere I need to update gcm reg id for app version update and OS update. For OS version update I'm trying to use `Build.VERSION.RELEASE` or `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to identify OS is updated with shared preference. Which one of the above should be used to achieve this ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: anyone please explain why -1, I can correct it for the next time. Is this question make no sense ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT will achieve this.